# How to prevent multiple logins from the same user in asp.net identity core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

i want to prevent multiple login from same user. i have add **ValidationInterval** in **ConfigureServices** block. but not working.

i put my code:

```
 services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>
(
   options => options.ValidationInterval=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
);
```

Kind regards,
Maksud

Comment: I'm interested in this too, hope someone will answer